# expandablelistview is not getting expanded when checkbox is added in parent xml

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, expandablelistview

I have developed the sample code of `ExpandableListView` in [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android). Data is being populated in Adapter and displaying in the `ExpandableListView` properly. but i am facing one severe issue of not expanding child view after tapping on `Groupview`.

The problem is when i add check box to the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)(parent xml) that is inflated in `getgroupView()` method child view does not get expanded after tapping `Groupview`.But, if checkbox is removed from the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) all works well.

*Similar question has been posted in StackOverflow, but nothing seems to work.*

Comment: Put your code we will fix it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you place an item that is `focusable` in a `list`, then the `list items` no longer respond to `clicks`

Try to set the `CheckBox` `android:focusable` attribute to `false`.

Comment: thankyou it worked.. dont have enough reputation to vote up your answer, else i would have.

Comment: can you tell me how to listen to checking those checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

In `groupView layout` set `android:focusable="true"` , `android:clickable="true"`.
For `checkbox` set `android:focusable="false"`