# ExpandableListview child position changing while scrolling

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using an expandablelistview in my code.It has 3 groups and each have 4 childs.And the child contains a SwitchButton. The issue is when I am clicking on one switch button, other switch buttons are also ticked. And when i am scrolling the first button checked will be unchecked.What is the issue here.Please help me.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shalom_radio_scedule_child_adapter, null);
    }

    TextView showTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.showTitleTextView);

 
    showEndTimeTextView.setText(showTime);

    final SwitchButton mSwitchReminder = (SwitchButton) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.scheduler_reminder_switch);
   
    mSwitchReminder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchButton view, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
           
                reminderStatus = "on";                  

            } else {
               
                reminderStatus = "off"

    return convertView;
}
```

And this is my layout for group header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Sunday"
            android:textColor="@color/nav_drawer_blue"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scheduler_image_expanded_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_row" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#e4e4e4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is layout for child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/showTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Amme Amme"
                android:textColor="@color/nav_drawer_blue"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/showTimeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="06:00 pm"
                    android:textColor="@color/nav_grey_light"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" - "
                    android:textColor="@color/nav_grey_light"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/showEndTimeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="08:30 pm"
                    android:textColor="@color/nav_grey_light"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <com.suke.widget.SwitchButton
                android:id="@+id/scheduler_reminder_switch"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:sb_checked="false"
                app:sb_checked_color="@color/nav_blue_light"
                app:sb_show_indicator="false" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scheduler_reminder_icon"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_reminder_small" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/parent_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/nav_blue_light" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please give me your code of adapter and layout.

Comment: please check this ans, it may be help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286769/expandablelistview-is-not-getting-expanded-when-checkbox-is-added-in-parent-xml

Comment: Refere this https://takeoffandroid.com/multiselectrecyclerview-2a5e83f32f42

Answer (score 0):

Use SparseBooleanArray in your Adapter class for preventing the selected position's state .

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    **SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;**

//    ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>> list;
    int rs;
    LayoutInflater li;
    Holder holder;
    Context context;
    int selectionTag = 0;
    private List<SortedTollModel> sortedTollModelList;

    public ListAdapter(Context ctx, int resources, List<SortedTollModel> sortedTollModelList) {

        context = ctx;
        rs = resources;
        this.sortedTollModelList = sortedTollModelList;
        li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(sortedTollModelList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sortedTollModelList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return sortedTollModelList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            v = li.inflate(rs, null);
            holder.tv_tollname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_toll_name);

            holder.tv_cost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cost);
            holder.select = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.ch_select);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
            holder.select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        }
        holder.tv_tollname.setText(sortedTollModelList.get(position).getName());
        String cost;
        try {
            cost = sortedTollModelList.get(position).getCost();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            cost = "30";
        }
        holder.tv_cost.setText(cost + " Rs");

        holder.select.setTag(position);
        **holder.select.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));**  
//set your SwitchButton state here.

        holder.select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    /*return list of selected tolls*/
    public List<Integer> getSelectedItemCount() {
        List<Integer> selectedCount = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTollModelList.size(); i++) {
            if (mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                selectedCount.add(i);
            }
        }
        return selectedCount;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false); 
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
            int p = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            **mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), true);**  // add selected position's state in `sparse boolen array`
            sendCostIntent(sortedTollModelList.get(p).getCost(), true);
        } else {
            int p = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            **mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), false);**
            selectionTag = 0;       //selection tag for identifiying from where broadcast is sent
            sendCostIntent(sortedTollModelList.get(p).getCost(), false);
        }
    }

    void sendCostIntent(String cost, Boolean cheak) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Constants.INTENT_ACTION_DATA_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra("cost", cost);
        intent.putExtra("selection_tag", selectionTag);
        Log.e("Toll Adapter cost : ", cost);
        intent.putExtra("cheak", cheak);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /*Selects all toll*/
    public void selectAll() {
        String cost = "";
        int totalCost = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTollModelList.size(); i++) {
            mCheckStates.put(i, true);
            holder.select.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(i));
            cost = sortedTollModelList.get(i).getCost();
            totalCost += Integer.parseInt(cost);
        }
        sendCostIntent(String.valueOf(totalCost), true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void unSelectAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTollModelList.size(); i++) {
            mCheckStates.put(i, false);
            holder.select.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(i));
            selectionTag = 1;
        }
        sendCostIntent(String.valueOf(0), false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView tv_tollname;
        TextView tv_cost;
        CheckBox select;

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use it.Can yo help me

Comment: Please add details .

Comment: Hi @Pallavi please add few more details. Thanks In Advance

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please see the code snippet. I hope it will help you.

Comment: @vijay chhalotre Please see the code snippet. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines in your xml file for **`ExpandableListview`**

```
 android:fadeScrollbars="false" 
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Comment: No. It's not solving the issue.

Comment: Did you run and check

Comment: Yes. I checked.